# How to create a string template: "some string {some_stub_var}"?

Tags: elixir

I want to create with a stub-template in it:

```
  my_str_template = "some string {some_stub_var}"
  # note that there's no variable "some_stub_var" in the current scope
```

So that sometime later in my application I'm able to do something like this:

```
my_str = my_str_template.format(some_stub_var: "my_real_string_var_123")
```

1) How to do that?

2) What's it called?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Regex.replace/3` with a function callback for simple string interpolation:

```
defmodule A do
  def format(string, bindings) do
    Regex.replace(~r/\{(\w+?)\}/, string, fn _, var -> bindings[String.to_existing_atom(var)] end)
  end
end

my_str_template = "some string {some_stub_var}"
IO.puts A.format(my_str_template, some_stub_var: "my_real_string_var_123")
```

Output:

```
some string my_real_string_var_123
```

You can also use EEx for this. The easiest way is to use `EEx.eval_string/2`:

```
my_str_template = "some string <%= some_stub_var %>"
IO.puts EEx.eval_string(my_str_template, some_stub_var: "my_real_string_var_123")
```

The more efficient way is to use `EEx.function_from_string` to compile the templates down to functions at compile time but it might be too cumbersome for such simple single line templates.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for a templating language.

There are many. A fairly simple one is called [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/).

[bbmustache](https://github.com/soranoba/bbmustache) is an implementation in `erlang`.

You can add it to your mix file like so:

```
  defp deps do
    [
      {:bbmustache, "~> 1.4"},
    ]
  end
```

and run `mix deps.get` to install.

Usage example:

```
iex(1)> :bbmustache.render("Hello {{who}}", %{ 'who' => "world" })
"Hello world"
```

A bit of a snag for this library is that the keys in the map must be charlists (single quoted).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EEx](https://hexdocs.pm/eex/EEx.html)

```
EEx.eval_string("foo <%= bar %>", bar: "baz")
```